# AWS Amplify How limit the result of observeQuery

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I used AWS Amplify datastore and I've make some Graphql requests with the Amplify.DataStore.query() api.
I noticed that, when using the Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery() I couldn't put some limitation on my request and it fetch all the database elements... When using Amplify.DataStore.query() I could.

**How can I put a limitation to only watch the update of the last 10 items of a table ?**

Here is my code:

```dart
 Stream<QuerySnapshot<Actuality>> getActualityStream() {
    return Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(
      Actuality.classType,
      sortBy: [
        Actuality.DATE.descending(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually alot easier than you think. The documentation at https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/data-access/q/platform/flutter/#predicates clearly shows the predicates you can use.
Example code:

```
late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Jobs>> streamJobs;
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamJobs =
        Amplify.DataStore.observeQuery(Jobs.classType,
            where: Jobs.USERID.contains(widget.userId));
}
```

As for the requirement to only bring back some information. You have two options as far as I can tell. Either generate a field that counds and call a
"where: ElementType.ID.between(1, 5)" dynamically checking the length -10. Else you could try at pagination. Not sure past that. Amplify is rather new.

Comment: That didn't answer my question :/

Comment: added some thoughts on that